# New package not working in cloud hosting?

Tags: laravel, cloud

I have done:

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

on my laravel project in Huawei Cloud, but new package is not working.

What should I do after update vendor?

Comment: does this package exists in composer.json file?

Comment: @omaresmaeel yes , it exists in composer.json